# Regex to match *.sublime-settings files

Tags: regex

```
Packages/Material Theme/widgets/Widget - Material-Theme.sublime-settings
Packages/DA UI/Widget - DA.sublime-settings
Packages/DA UI/Widget - DA (Windows).sublime-settings
Packages/TextMate/TextMate Syntax Definition (JSON).sublime-settings

Packages/DA UI/Widget - DA (Linux).sublime-settings
Packages/DA UI/Widget - DA (OSX).sublime-settings
Packages/User/YAML.sublime-settings
```

Could anyone have the time to implement a regex to match the first 4 and not the last 3.

**rules**

- after `Packages` there must be at least one folder.
- the folder right after `Packages` must not be "User".
- the name (after the final slash) can optionally contain a pair of parenths right before the `.` that may not contain the name of other platforms; if the current platform is Windows, OSX and Linux are not accepted (we assume that the current platform is represented by a variable `platform`)

This is my try:

`(?i)Packages/(?:[^/]+?/([^()]+?(?: \((?!OSX|Linux)\))?)\.sublime-settings)`

It doesn't match 3 and 4 and matches the last.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: no it's a typo, i just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)^Packages/(?!User)(?:(?![^/]+$).)+/[^(.]+(?:\((?!OSX|Linux).+\))?\.sublime-settings
```

https://regex101.com/r/kgJMq4/2

- `(?!User)` - Negative lookahead for `User` right after the first slash
- `(?:(?![^/]+$).)+` - Repeat any character that's not followed by non-slash characters and the end of the string
- `/[^(.]+` - Match the final slash, then repeat non-parentheses, non-dot characters, so as to check for an optional group:
- `(?:\((?!OSX|Linux).+\))?` - Parentheses surrounding a phrase that does not start with `OSX` or `Linux`

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, what if i want to capture the name of the folder after `Packages` ?

Comment: Repeat non-slashes in a group after the first slash with `([^/]+)` https://regex101.com/r/kgJMq4/3